# Reading Image from the Local Folder in Objective C

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I need to Read a Image from the specific URL .

It works fine with WWW .  but it returns a nil when the URL pointing the Local Folder .

```
// Works 
NSString *sampleData = @"http://blogs-images.forbes.com/ericsavitz/files/2011/05/apple-logo2.jpg";

// Returns nil 
NSString *sampleData = @"USER/user2/...";
```

Note : 
 I am changing the NSString to NSURL and creating the UIImage .

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: data];

UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData: [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url]];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are supplying a relative pathname for the file URL.  That relative pathname is interpreted relative to the current working directory of the running application, which isn't guaranteed to be anything in particular, and so is almost certainly not what you want.

You can either supply an absolute path - one that starts with '/' - or set your app's current working directory to something explicit, like your user's Documents folder.

Comment: I need to Read the image from the Documents Directory of the iPhoneSimulator

Comment: This will get you the absolute path to your app's Documents folder.  It works both on the simulator and on devices: `[NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"Documents"]`

Comment: Its works .. 
I was using 

`NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains (NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); 
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];`

Thanks for simplifying my code ..

Comment: That's a little less efficient, but should have worked.  Just for tutorial purposes, try using NSLog() to print the pathname you create that way to the console.  Maybe there is a problem with it.  Did you remember to separate the filename from the directory path with a '/' character?

Comment: Ya it worked well . I made a mistake in creating UIImage instance .Thanks

Answer (score 1):

you probably should have a look into the NSBundle Class.
Methods like

`- (NSURL *)URLForResource:(NSString *)name withExtension:(NSString *)extension subdirectory:(NSString *)subpath`

or

`- (NSString *)pathForResource:(NSString *)name ofType:(NSString *)extension`

is probably what you want

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can NOT read file from such path you given: "USER/user2/...", the file must in your App bundle or in your App's sandbox.

Second, check your path string if there was some texts need to be encoded in URL. Try:

`NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[data stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];`

Also, if the url is not nil, you should also check if your `[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];` is returning nil. If so, it means your URL is not correct so the method cannot find your file.

P.S., You are mistyping your image create code, you should call `alloc` before `imageWithData:`.

Comment: Xuzhe , Actually I was trying to read from the Path .I have tried it with Bundle it worked fine .

Answer (score 0):

You should do something like to get the local url :

```
NSString *docDir = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *pngFilePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", docDir, nameOfFile];
```

and finaly, load your image :

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:pngFilePath];
```

Comment: Ya it worked fine .
I used dataWithContentsOfUrl instead .
Thanks .

Answer (score 0):

Try these instead

```
NSString *path =   @"USER/user2/.../xxx.xxx";
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
BOOL isFileExist = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:path];
UIImage *image;
if (isFileExist) {
    image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
}
else {
    // do something.<br>
}
```